# Legendre transformation and thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a question about Legendre transformation.

Imagine that we have a function depending on $x$.

$$ df = \frac{df}{dx} dx = u(x) dx$$

We assume that this quantity has to be minimized (for example $f$ could be $F$, the Helmoltz function (where we only vary the volume for example).

So : $$ dF(V)=\frac{dF}{dV} dV = P(V) dV $$

We are interested in studying the equilibrium in function of the pressure (we apply a constant pressure on our system and we want to see how the volume will be).

As 
$$ d(PV)=PdV+VdP $$

We can define $G=F-PV$ such as
$$ dG=-VdP$$

And here is my question:

I want to transform a function $F$ depending only on the volume to a function $G$ depending only on the pressure.

I know from my knowledge on thermodynamics  that $G$ has to be minimized at equilibrium.

But can it be proved mathematically from the fact that $F$ must be minimized at equilibrium in regards of $V$, so $G$ has to be minimized in regards of $P$? I didn't succeed to do it.

Or it can't be proved mathematically : we have to admit that $G$ has to be minimized by using law of thermodynamics (it is not a consequence of Legendre transformation).

(by the way if someone can help me on this thread I would be grateful :D [Why is the the differential of Helmoltz free energy dT dependent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281776/why-is-the-the-differential-of-helmoltz-free-energy-dt-dependent/281782#281782) )

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1147.pdf you might want to read a bit about the mathematical properties of Legendre transforms. I don't find my old course scripts from stat mech, but I think most of what you say can be shown. The linked article might be a good start.

Comment: Please refer Thermodynamics by Callen. There is a chapter on thermodynamic potentials where such proofs are given.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that the statements that "Helmholtz Free Energy is minimized at equilbrium" and "Gibbs Free Energy is minimized at equilbrium" are referring to two *different* notions of minimizing. In the former case, you minimize at *fixed volume*; in the latter case, you minimize at *fixed pressure*.

Once you understand this then the equivalence of the two statements is easy to see. Imagine for generality that in addition to pressure/volume your system has another parameter $\alpha$. (For example, $\alpha$ could be the ionization fraction of water molecules.) Then you have
$$ dF = -P dV + \kappa d\alpha$$
where $\kappa = (\partial F)/(\partial \alpha)_V$. This implies that $$dG = V dP + \kappa d\alpha.$$
Now you see that the statement "Helmholtz free energy is minimized at fixed volume (dV =0)" and "Gibbs Free energy is minimized at fixed pressure (dP=0)" are *both* equivalent to $\kappa=0$.